# why? error? 'Car'member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#-4.0

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 namespace half_test {
  class Car {
    private int printInfo;
    public int PrintInfoMethod {
      get {
        return printInfo;
      }
      set {
        printInfo=value;
      }
    }
    public void Car() {
      Console.WriteLine("<" + printInfo);
    }
  }
  class Engine {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Engine blf=new Engine("BLF", 1597);
      Engine bny=new Engine("BVY", 1984);
      Engine blg=new Engine("BLG", 1389);
      Car[] cars=new Car[4];
      cars[0]=new Car("GOLF E", blf);
      cars[1]=new Car("GOLF E", blf);
      cars[2]=new Car("GOLF E", blf);
      cars[3]=new Car("GOLF E", blf);
      foreach (Car car in cars) car.printInfo();
    }
  }
}
```

this error point.

why error?

When I compile the above code I get this error:

> Error: 'Car': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Why? How can I resolve this?

I want view this screenshat.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chV1r.png)

Comment: I've never written a line of C# in my life, but I'm guessing `public void Car()` should be `public Car()`.

Comment: @Biffen: Only if it's intended to be a constructor. It's not really clear what it's intended to be at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet True, I was just going by the name.

Answer (score 3):

> Why?

That's just the rules of the language. If you're creating a class called `Car`, it can't contain any members (properties, methods, fields, nested types, events) called `Car`. It would be *really* confusing if this were allowed, IMO.

> How can I resolve this?

By renaming your method. At the moment it's called `Car()`, which doesn't describe what it does. How about calling it `PrintInfo`? It's not clear why you've got a *property* called `PrintInfoMethod` either... or why you're calling constructors that don't exist in the code you've shown.

If you want a `Car` to have some sort of descriptive text, I'd call that `Description`, and if you really want a method to print that description, give it an appropriate name. Example:

```
class Car
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public void PrintDescription()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"< {Description}");
    }
}
```